# Running a bash script in a PythonOperator works in airflow 1.10.6 and not in 1.10.7

Tags: python, bash, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I was trying to create a DAG which consists of two PythonOperators. One of which runs a simple bash script and the other one simply prints an output to the logs. I have been using this method to run some complex bash scripts using the python operator for quite some time now and they worked fine until I upgraded from airflow 1.10.6 to 1.10.7. Now the PythonOperator keeps running infinitely while also stating that the last heartbeat from scheduler was received 10 minutes ago even though the first function ran fine and the scheduler has been in running state all this time.

I tried leaving the task running for sometime in the hopes of it getting completed but the job ultimately failed while indicating that airflow had to SIGKILL the task since it was not responding. Following is the code for the simplest DAG that I have tried so far:

```
import airflow
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'provide_context': True,
}

dag = DAG('Test_Job', schedule_interval="@once", default_args=args)

def a(**kwargs):
    command_to_execute = "scalac --version"
    stream = os.popen(command_to_execute)
    output = stream.read()
    print("Scalac done")
    print(output)

def b(**kwargs):
    print("Hi")



A = PythonOperator(task_id='A', python_callable=a, dag = dag)
B = PythonOperator(task_id='B', python_callable=b, dag = dag)

A.set_upstream(B)

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    b()
    a()
```

I reverted back to 1.10.6 when this problem persisted and now it is working as expected. Does this mean this method is incompatible with airflow 1.10.7? If so, how this can be achieved in 1.10.7?

PS: I am aware of the fact that ideally BashOperator should be used to run bash script but due to some product requirements I have to do this using PythonOperator.

Comment: Did you find any solution?